# Fail to import android support v4 or v7 in library using productFlavors

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library, android-productflavors

I am setting up an **Android Library** with different **productFlavors**. 
The library has a **light** and a **full** flavor. The file is setted up correctly:

`src/main/java/com/example/...` for main classes
`src/full/java/com/example/...` for full classes
`src/light/java/com/example/...` for light classes

Android Studio correctly understood this and added a `(full)` to the full flavor.

**ISSUE :** The dependencies like `okhttp` is working as expected but NOT the `appcompat-v7`. Everything using `ViewPager`, `FragmentActivity`, `RecyclerView`. I've tried added the dependencies to the `fullCompile` but it didn't work either. The dependencies is not resolved by Android Studio, import is not working, except ok `okhttp`, `exoplayer` and so on.

I've tried `Invalidate Cache/Restart`, `clean Project`, `Resync gradle`, none worked.

**Library** `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    publishNonDefault true

    productFlavors {
        full {
        }
        light {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    fullCompile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    fullCompile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    fullCompile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    fullCompile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
}
```

**App** `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    buildTypes {
        release {
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        full {
        }
        light {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    fullCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'fullRelease')
    lightCompile project(path: ':library', configuration: 'lightRelease')
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the error produced in gradle?

Comment: when build the app, it says `Error:(1073, 64) error: package ViewPager does not exist`. If I browse the classes, `ViewPager` import is not resolved and result an error in that classes. @droidpl

Comment: If you use in some place a viewPager and this class is not in the full/light version in the corresponding src/light or src/full folder, it won't be imported since with the fullCompile you are saying in this version the library is available. Can you recheck where this file crashing is?

Comment: @droidpl I've the base code placed in `src/main`, and the error happen in the `full` flavor. I am using `fullRelease` build variant of the app.

Comment: I have provided you a possible solution. Please try it.

Comment: If this doesn't work execute the following command and post the response: ```./gradlew app:dependencies```

Comment: @droidpl here you are https://gist.github.com/HugoGresse/865adcb5339b6671448e

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97877/discussion-between-droidpl-and-hugo-gresse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the configuration in the app gradle. When it is related to a library, the configurations are not declared properly. Try:

```
configurations {
    fullDebugCompile
    fullReleaseCompile
    lightDebugCompile
    lightReleaseCompile
}

dependencies {
...
    fullDebugCompile project(path:":library", configuration:"fullDebug")
    fullReleaseCompile project(path:":library", configuration:"fullRelease")
    lightDebugCompile project(path:":library", configuration:"lightDebug")
    lightReleaseCompile project(path:":library", configuration:"lightRelease")
}
```

**Long explanation**

The gradle android plugin uses different implementations for the app and the library, called `AppVariant` and `LibraryVariant` respectively. Sometimes the way variants and build types work is different in both kind of projects. In this case, some time ago the libraries always were compiled in the release build type within a given variant, something that made library projects not so flexible as apps were.

That is why they decided to enable the `publishNonDefault` option and bring support in Android Studio for this kind of behaviours, so you can use different builds of a library in different builds of an app, but you have to specify which build uses which library. This is the reason that makes you declare the `configurations` explicitly.

The convention name used by the Android Build Tools team is `{buildType}{flavor}TaskName`, so for the classpath configuration you have to use the same name.

All of this process has a downside, which is if you publish non default dependencies, the android plugin will ensure all of the possible library configurations are compiled before your app is built, so the build time can increase a bit (depending on the library size)